# c# get and set accessors datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am receiving unreachable code detected in my properties. This worked for regular string fields but not for DateTime data type.

```
private DateTime m_RenewalDate;
    public DateTime M_RenewalDate
            {
                get { return m_RenewalDate != null ? m_RenewalDate : DateTime.MinValue; }
                set { m_RenewalDate = value; }
            }
```

this is my sqldatareader

```
reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("M_RENEWALDATE"))
```

Comment: private DateTime m_RenewalDate;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As driis said in his answer, `m_RenewalDate == null` is always false as `DateTime` is a value type and things declared to be value types cannot be null.

To have the `get` the behavior of returning `DateTime.MinValue` from `M_RenewalDate` in the case that `M_RENEWALDATE` is `null` your reader code should look more like this

```
object renewalDate = reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("M_RENEWALDATE"));

if (Equals(renewalDate, DBNull.Value))
{
    yourObject.M_RenewalDate = DateTime.MinValue;
}
else
{
    yourObject.M_RenewalDate = (DateTime) renewalDate;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

`DateTime` is a value type, and can not be null. Therefore, the code in the getter is unreachable:

```
return m_RenewalDate != null ? // always evaluates to true
       m_RenewalDate :         // and therefore always returns this
       DateTime.MinValue;      // The code never hits this case.
```

If your field in the database can be null, perhaps you want to declare the property as a nullable DateTime: `DateTime?`.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` is a value type and cannot be null. To compare with a null value in the database, use `DBNull.Value`